# How to detect old doc format in Word js api

Tags: ms-word, office-js, apps-for-office

I have created a taskpane addin for word that is using the [Document.getFileAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync#support-details) method to get the document contents in Compressed format (docx).
This works correctly for .docx files, but unsurprisingly fails if an old .doc file is used.

I get the following error:

```
code: 5001
message: "An internal error has occurred."
name: "Internal Error"
```

Is there a way to detect documents in invalid formats before calling getFileAsync? 
I have tried reading the document properties format value using the following code:

```
return Word.run(function (context) {
  var properties = context.document.properties;
  context.load(properties, "format");
  return context.sync()
    .then(function () {
      return properties.format;
    });
});
```

But the returned value is always an empty string for both docx and doc files.

I would like to be able to detect old file formats so that I can display an appropriate error message to the users.

Answer (score 0):

`getFileAsync()` method works for `.docx` file only. Just to detect the correct file you can simply check the extension of the file: `fname.substr((~-fname.lastIndexOf('.') >>> 0) + 2)` where `fname` is filename here. And prompt your message accordingly.